# Haskell: parsec key value pairs (key: value)

Tags: haskell, parsec

how would I parse a file containing keys and values using parsec into `[[(String, String)]]`?

```
key1: value 1 key2: value 2
key1: value 1 key2: value 2
key1: value 1 key2: value 2
```

the key is one word, the value can be more words.

I have tried

```
tag :: GenParser Char st Tag
tag = do
  name <- key
  value <- manyTill anyChar (try key)
  return (name, value)

key :: GenParser Char st String
key = do
  name <- many (noneOf ": ")
  char ':'
  return name

> parse (many tag) "" "key1: value 1 key2: value 2"
Right [("key1"," value 1 ")]
```

Comment: A less ambiguous specification of the file's grammar would be appreciated. Is `[("key 1", "value 1")]` a correct result?

Comment: @identity No, the key is supposed to be one word without spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have changed the `tag` function to test both newline and next key, and that works for me.

```
tag :: GenParser Char st Tag
tag = do
  name <- key
  value <- manyTill anyChar ((test newline) <|> (test key))
  return (name, strip value)

test :: GenParser Char st a -> GenParser Char st ()
test p = lookAhead $ try p >> return ()

key :: GenParser Char st String
key = do
  name <- many1 (noneOf ": \n\r")
  char ':'
  return name
```